# Django query reverse relationship without foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm currently working on a Django library to manage images of multiple resolutions ([django-multires](https://github.com/miki725/django-multires/tree/develop)) where I am stuck optimizing a reserve relationship query. Before I explain the issue, let me try to explain what I am trying to achieve.

**Background**

The idea is to store multiple resolutions of an image however keep references to the original image in terms of image paths instead of foreign keys. I think an example will make more sense:

```
# the goal is to store multiple resolutions for 'image' field
class FooModel(models.Model):
    image = MultiresImageField(...)

# MultiresImage.source will be the identical to FooModel.image
# so MultiresImage.source will act sort of like a foreign key
class MultiresImage(models.Model):
    source = models.ImageField(...)
    ...
```

Using this approach instead of using a foreign key (or generic foreign key) to link to the source image allows to add multiple `MultiresImageField`s to the source model:

```
class FooModel(models.Model):
    image  = MultiresImageField(...)
    image2 = MultiresImageField(...)
```

Now lets say you need to get all different resolutions for an image field within the source model:

```
foo = FooModel(...)
foo.image.get_all_multires_images()
# which behind the scenes will do something similar to
return MultiresImage.objects.filter(source=foo.image.name)
```

That works well until you need to query multiple `FooModel` instances in which case for each model instance I am forced to do a db lookup to get all resolutions for that model:

```
sources = FooModel.objects.filter(...)
for source in sources:
    # this incurs a db query
    foo.image.get_all_multires_images()
```

Usually I would use `prefetch_related` to do the performance optimization however in here I can't because my multires model does not have a foreign key to the source model hence reverse relationship does not exist on the source model.

**Question**

So my question is how can the above query be optimized?

**Some current thoughts**

- Since I am making a custom model field, I could use `contribute_to_class` to manually add a reverse relationship to source model however I can't figure out how?
- Another though is to use `Prefetch` API in [Django>=1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) but I can't figure out how to make that work as well.

Comment: Without more information on your custom MuliResImageField, it is hard to give you proper advice. What I do not understand anyway is: why you should not be able to use a simple ForeignKey. E.g. image= models.ForeignKey(MultiResImage); image2=models.ForeignKey(MultiResImage).

Comment: I want the `MultiresImageField` to be backwards compatible with regular Django image field. You can see the current code for `MultiresImageField` at github however I dont think any of it is relevant to solve this query issue.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, but probably not most elegant solution would be to write a kind of helper class:

```
def prefetch_related_images(image_queryset):
    multires_images = MultiresImage.objects.filter(source__in=[image.name for image in image_queryset ])
    for image in image_queryset:
        image.multires_images = []
        for multires_image in multires_images:
            if multires_image.source == image.name:
                image.multires_images.append(multires_image)
```

And well, a more elegant solution could be along the lines on your thought on contribute_to_class. Why don't you try something like a Generic Relationship:

```
class MultiresImage(models.Model):
    source = models.ImageField(...)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image_target= GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

and then amend contribute_to_class like that:

```
def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
    """
    Attached necessary garbage collection signals.
    """
    super(MultiresImageField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)

    setattr(cls,'%_source',  GenericRelation(MultiresImage)
```

And then handle the details of managing the relationship via the signals (as you already do).

Comment: That is roughly what I do now. I am hoping to find a way to hook up into Django's API. Thanx anyway.